# 3.6 Camera Follow Path, Need to smoothly slow down the camera

Tags: animation, constraints

I am trying to have my camera follow a bezier circle that's been elongated into an oval, approaching my object of interest.  So my camera has two modifiers, Follow Path and Track To.  As my camera approaches the object I would like to to smoothly slow down.  After lots of searching I've not found exactly how to use keyframes since the 'Animate Path' on the Follow Path modifier seems to do all the work.  I guess I am expecting that I can use the Follow Path and somehow create keyframes that I can control but so far nothing is working.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Maybe I need to learn/use the Dope Sheet but so far I'm stuck.

In the image I keep seeing my camera location switch to {0,1,1} even though I've set it to the Orgin {0,0,0} and that too is confusing[image]

Comment: Here's a tutorial showing how to alter the speed of a camera while following a path: https://youtu.be/1byaQygtcpc.

Answer (score 0):

If you've clicked on the constraint *Animate Path* button, it has automatically created an animation for the curve, but you can remove it: Select the curve, go into *Object Data > Path Animation*, right click on the *Evaluation* value and *Clear Keyframes*. Now you can keyframe this *Evaluation* value in order to move your camera the way you want.

[image]

Comment: Thx moonboots, so I see that after that I need to keyframe the Camera's Follow Path Offset and NOT use the BezierCircle Path Animation Evaluation Time at all, but I still have the Path Animation checked - does that matter?

Comment: You can either keyframe the Evaluation value, or the Offset. As for the Path Animation, activate it