blender camera moving setting
I want to manipulate the camera in Blender. I've managed to make it move along the curve, but I'd like to set it up to move along the curve, pause in the middle to rotate slightly, and then continue moving along the curve. However, it's only moving along the curve without pausing for rotation. I would appreciate some advice.

Pleae add an image of your settings! Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender then follow How to upload an image to a post. Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299334/3-6-camera-follow-path-need-to-smoothly-slow-down-the-camera.

i assume, that you have created an object constraint "follow" path, and pressed the animate path button like this:

what Blender does by this, is adding an animation to evaluation time:

so if you select the curve you can see that the "evaluation" field is green.
If you open the graph editor, you will see the so called "fcurve".

if you click on "modifiers", you will see, how the curve is generated:

of course, you can manipulate that by changing values, but in your case, i would just delete that modifier, hover over the evaluation time field and press I to insert a keyframe.
then e.g. go to frame 50, enter 50 in the evaluation time and hover over it again and press I again, your graph editor should look like this:

now just select that one keyframe:

press shift-d x and move it:

then press shift d again and move it to the right and on y axis to 100:

if you play the animation now, it should pause.
during the pause time you can animate you camera as you like.
Hope that helps.

Your comment has been really helpful. Thank you so much for assisting in many aspects.

@biginner If the answer is correct please mark it as such   ;)

If you use the Follow Path constraint, don't click on the Animate Path of the constraint, otherwise it will create a Generator modifier for the curve, you can still remove it: select the curve, open the Graph Editor, open the N panel > Modifiers > remove the modifier.
Now instead create some keyframes on the Offset value of the constraint. You could also create some keyframes on the curve: select the curve, go into the Data panel > Path Animation and keyframe the Evaluation Time.

Your comment has been really helpful, too. Thank you so much.

@biginner If the answer is correct please mark it as such ;) - click on the checkmark left of the answer
